# Best way to parse a file (LAS) with differents parts?

Tags: java, file, parsing, log-ascii-standard

I'm looking forward to parsing a LAS file (Log ASCII Standard), this type of file has different parts with different syntax's, example here:

```
"file.las"
~V
VERS  .   3.00    : Comments
DLM   .   COMMA
~Curve
RHOB.M
~Data
1000.5,  35.2
1001.0,  40.6
```

Here's what I'm currently doing to parse my file, I'm using different for loop for each Syntax.

```html
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

System.out.print("Searching ~V");
for (String line = file.readLine(); line != null; line = file.readLine()) {
  if(line.contains("~V")){
    System.out.println("Success");
    break;
  }else{
    //Do Nothing
  }
}

System.out.print("Searching VERS");
for (String line = file.readLine(); line != null; line = file.readLine()) {
  line = line.trim();
  if(line.startsWith("VERS.")){
  line = line.replaceAll(" ", "");
  String lineWithoutComment = line.split(":")[0];
  lasFileVO.setVersion(lineWithoutComment);
  break;
  }else{
     //Do Nothing
  }
}

if(lasFileVO.getVersion.startWith("3.0")){
  System.out.print("Searching DLM");
  //For loop
}
```

The parsing is working, and I find it very easy to understand for the other developers (which is a good thing).

Is there a better way to parse a file, containing different parts with different syntax, then my series of For Loops?

**EDIT:**

I already saw the while loop way, but I don't see how I could implement that:

```html
while ( (line = bufRead.readLine()) != null)
{    
    
}
```

... with a file with different syntaxes at different places without adding a tons of conditions. With a list of for loop, I don't need to check a lot of condition for each line.

Comment: Please if you downvote, tell me why, i can't improve without advices. I'm still searching for the best way to parse file with differents parts. Thanks

Comment: Did you make it working? i'm also trying to read a LAS file using Java

Answer (score -1):

You have this project that can help you in parsing LAS files

http://www.jwitsml.org/dlis.html

This is an example using this library:

```
 File file = new File("data.las");

 // Instantiate a reader and read the LAS file
 LasFileReader reader = LasFileReader(file);
 LasFile lasFile = reader.readFile();

 // Loop over all curves
 for (LasCurve curve : lasFile.getCurves()) {
   System.out.println("Curve name..: " + curve.getName());
   System.out.println("Description.: " + curve.getDescription());
   System.out.println("Unit........: " + curve.getUnit());
   System.out.println("value type..: " + curve.getValueType());
   // The curve values are accessed by curve.getValue(index)
 }
```

Comment: Hi, this project is not public, and you can't download it. Moreover it doesn't answer my question about the best way to parse a file with different part.

Comment: The project is open source and you can download it. http://www.jwitsml.org/download.html

Comment: jwitsml-1.1.jar doesn't contain the "logio.jar" or any class from here http://www.jwitsml.org/dlis/javadoc/index.html, which contains the LAS Part. Where can i download logio.jar ?